# SEO effect of redirecting pages back to the home page with a hash anchor

Tags: seo, redirects

We have a one page site. There are different sections, linked to via anchor links. Since we built it using WordPress such every section is a unique page behind the scenes. The problem is that Google indexed these pages as well. That isn't bad for our search results, but our site shouldn't be used via those pages.  It should be used only on the home page.

Does it affect my search reputation if I redirect visitors back to the correct section on the home page via JavaScript?   For example `/contact/` would get  redirected back to `/#contact`.  I use JavaScript for the purpose of only redirecting users and not the bots. The pages themselves are good for us.  The have good linking and good content.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much better not to have extra pages, like `example.com/#contact` that link back to the home page, and just use `example.com/contact` as a link in itself. Google prefers whatever is the most simple and clear for them, which would be separate pages like `example.com/contact.html` for example.

Indicating separate 'pages' like `example.com/#contact` would be second best because Google displays results like the root URL to your site, then below it says "Jump to: #contact", for example.

Comment: Yeah but they exists I can't change that. So the question how to handle it best. I have now one page which is build on four pages. I am not sure wether google acknowledge the anchor links or just indexes the actual pages

Comment: Also that wasn't really my question :-) do you know wether google even recognize a JS based redirection or not? Due to the single pages the SEO result is not bad. So the question is really does Google check that I redirect user back or not and when yes do they punish it

Comment: I just googled this and I think the best thing is to make the pages that link back to /# pages 301 Moved Permanently redirects

Comment: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Comment: I'm just looking up what the code is for this

Comment: Here's a link that shows different ways of making a 301 redirect:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301#Example

Comment: Yeah I already read about 301 the question is, when 301 is set, does Google index it further?

Comment: +1 thanks Alex for your efforts I will just try it with pages and JS redirect. I want to test wether that is useful to combine the advantages from a single page for the visitor with the advantages from unique pages for the SEO.

Comment: "Yeah I already read about 301 the question is, when 301 is set, does Google index it further? –" I think that it doesn't. 301 means moved permanently, so Google will probably un-index it and set where it redirects to to be indexed instead

Comment: ..best do it by editing the .htaccess file, if you can. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/